# building aosp (android) on CENTOS 5.10 x86_64 standard server fails

Tags: android-source

we are trying to build AOSP (android-4.4.2_r1) on our CENTOS 5.10 x86_64 standard server b/c it has a lot of processors and ram. soon after we run make -j32 2> error.log the build stops. the error.log shows the following errors. can anyone tell us why?

```
find: src: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/m4: unrecognized option `--gnu'
Try `/usr/bin/m4 --help' for more information.
/root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as)
/root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as)
/root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as)
/root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /root/android/source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as)
/usr/bin/m4: unrecognized option `--gnu'
Try `/usr/bin/m4 --help' for more information.
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/checkpolicy_intermediates/policy_parse.cpp] Broken pipe
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this issue we upgraded our centos server from 5.10 to 6.5. however, we didn't follow source.android.com instructions on how to prep the server. instead we simply ran make -j32 and then fixed any subsequent errors.

one thing we noticed was we had to install 32bit packages on a 64bit server. we also ended up ditching AOSP for CM.

lastly, and this was more a business decision, we bought a cheap tablet that had an official CM11 ROM: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_p3110 so we could at least have some instruction set.